# how to save a structure in a vector and print out those values in C language?

Tags: c, list, structure

For this program, I want to know how to save this information (functions of a robot with price) in a vector:

```
move-$100    
jump - $200        
pick up- $350       
spin around - $250    
laser - $1000    
throw - $800    
shred - $450
```

SO I have this so far:

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char name[30] ;
        int price;
    } t_piece ;

    typedef struct
    {
        t_person P ;
        t_piece vec [ 500 ] ;
        int amount ;
     }t_client ;
```

How to store the pieces (above) in the vector?
Should I save it in a vector of pieces/functions? something like:

```
         vec[0].name=move;
         vec[0].price=100;
         vec[1].name=jump;
         vec[1].price=200;
```

Would this be in main or `int`/`void`/`t_piece`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### c++ approach:

to store struct in a vector you declare first the vector

```
 vector<struct name_of_your_struct> name_of_vector; //the vector is still empty
```

then you declare a variable of struct like that

```
 struct name_of_your_struct     name_of_variable_type_struct;
```

you fill your struct with the adequate informations (first example move-$100)

```
name_of_variable_type_struct.name="move";
name_of_variable_type_struct.price=100;
```

then you push it inside your vector

```
name_of_vector.push_back(name_of_variable_type_struct);
```

you can repeat that many times with a loop

```
while(1)
{
     cin >> name_of_variable_type_struct.name;
     cin >> name_of_variable_type_struct.price;
     cin.ignore();
     name_of_vector.push_back(name_of_variable_type_struct);
}
```

### c approach

to store struct in a vector you declare first the vector

```
 struct name_of_your_struct* name_of_vector=malloc(nsize_vector_chosen*sizeof(struct name_of_your_struct));
```

you fill your vector with the adequate informations (first example move-$100)

```
strcpy(name_of_vector[0].name,"move");
name_of_vector[0].price=100;
```

you can repeat that many times with a loop

```
i=0;
while(i<size_vector_chosen)
{
         scanf("%s",string);
         strcpy(name_of_vector[i].name,string);

         scanf("%d",&price_number);
         name_of_vector[i].price=price_number;
         i++;
}
```

Comment: I have trouble switching between C and C++, but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: close the topic if you have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Given the `t_client` structure, if you want to read a number of the `t_piece` values from a data file into the client, you'll need to keep track of how many entries are in the array (that should probably be another field in the structure, unless `amount` is the number of entries).

Given:

```
t_client client;
```

You would be storing values into:

```
strcpy(client.vec[i].name, "move");
client.vec[i].prive = 100;
```

You'll be working with a loop of some sort, so you'll increment `i` on each iteration, making sure you don't overflow the limit of 500 entries, etc.

Actually reading those values is at least mildly tricky; the file is rather irregular, and the spaces in the names complicate things a little.  I'd probably read a line at a time, and split it taking the data up to the dash, minus any trailing blanks, as the name and the data following the `$` as the price.  You can use a string search function such as `strchr()` to find the right locations.

Comment: thanks for that new approach. I'll start with that! On a side note, any good ways to work on my algorithm/analysis skills (books)?